# Getting 400 Bad Request the first time I am sending a POST request to an OAuth 2.0 secured endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am building an OAuth 2.0 secured Spring 3.0.4 application and I am getting a "Required request body is missing" exception the first time I send a POST request to the following endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/api/instructor_requests")
    public InstructorRequest saveInstructorRequest(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser principal,
            @RequestBody InstructorRequestDto instructorRequestDto) {
//        String sub = principal.getAttribute("sub");
//        System.out.println(sub);
        return new InstructorRequest();
    }
```

Subsequent calls to the endpoint return 200.

Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

    public SecurityConfig(LogoutHandler logoutHandler) {
        this.logoutHandler = logoutHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("api/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler);

        return http.build();
    }
```

InstructorRequestDto class

```
@Data
public class InstructorRequestDto {
    @Size(min = 5)
    private String instructorRequestText;
}
```

I tried playing around with the configuration, but I believe I am setting everyting up correctly.